# How do I add a custom CSS file for default theme?

Tags: 8, theming

For example - I have enabled [Zircon](https://www.drupal.org/project/zircon) as my default theme. I want the user menu account to appear on left. 
I want to add a custom CSS file where I can write a CSS elements and add to a default theme on site.

Comment: You can define your own library and attach it via hook_page_attachments or you can alter the theme's library and add your css in there.

Answer (score 3):

> In Drupal 8, stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) are loaded through the same system for modules (code) and themes, for everything: asset libraries. Asset libraries can contain one or more CSS assets, one or more JS assets and one or more JS settings.

More details on 
https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets

Answer (score 2):

Add your custom CSS file to  `themes/zircon/css/` lest suppose your file name is `yourfile.css`,
then open  `zircon.libraries.yml` and  add your Css file name to end of this section

```
css:
  base:
   includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css: {}
   includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css: {}
   includes/fonts/oswald_regular/stylesheet.css: {}
   includes/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css: {}
   includes/slick/slick/slick.css: {}
   includes/slick/css/style.css: {}
   includes/monokai/monokai.min/css: {}
   includes/flexslider/flexslider.css: {}
   css/html.css: {}
   css/page.css: {}
   css/block.css: {}
   css/view.css: {}
   css/slideshow.css: {}
   css/responsive.css: {}
   css/print.css: { media: print }
   css/yourfile.css: {}
```

save and close the file  and **clear the cache**.

Comment: adding a css file name in zircon.libraries.yml is giving an error-The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Comment: @NewBorn-Drupalist try with put space after colon ` css/yourfile.css: {}`

Comment: this is bad advice. Composer will delete edits on the next update if Zircon is a contrib theme.